# TypeError: Cannot call method "substring" of undefined

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am searching through a google sheet using app script with :

```
for (i in main_rows) {
  var row = main_rows[i];
  var dates_followed = row[10];
  if (dates_followed.substring(0, 2) == "TBD") {
    tbd_index = i;
  }
}
```

looking for the first string that starts with TBD. I'm getting the error in the title. I understand why this is happening, but what is the best way in JS / apps script to deal with an empty cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest simply checking if the row has a `truthy` value like so:

```
for (i in main_rows) {
  var row = main_rows[i];
  var dates_followed = row[10];
  if (dates_followed && dates_followed.substring(0, 2) == "TBD") {
    tbd_index = i;
  }
}
```